# How to turn off Dozer message in log4j.xml?

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss7.x, dozer

I am using Dozer library in my application.
But i'm getting following log while my application is running

"INFO  [org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9100-1) Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper."

I am using Jboss AS 7.1.1.

Please help me how to turn off this info message of Dozer library in Log4j.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `category` with priority level `OFF`.

```
<category name="org.dozer">
    <priority value="OFF" />
</category>
```

See more in [*Log4j XML Configuration Primer*](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat).